# Python app scheduler issue on Raspberry pi, i got error like this "python[2132]: WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Execution of job"

Tags: python, pi-zero, services

I an using **Raspberry PI zero W** and connected 5 sensors to getting reading from sensors. i used **services** for start the sensors scripts and i installed **python** **apscheduler** for time sequence.

Sometime working, suddenly raise issue like "**python[2132]: WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Execution of job " (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2019-10-04 10:18:01 EDT)" skipped: maximum number of running i**"

Oct 04 10:19:01 RPZ-3 python[2132]: WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Execution of job " (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2019-10-04 10:19:01 EDT)" skipped: maximum number of running i
Oct 04 10:20:01 RPZ-3 python[2132]: WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Execution of job " (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2019-10-04 10:20:01 EDT)" skipped: maximum number of running i
Oct 04 10:21:01 RPZ-3 python[2132]: WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Execution of job " (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2019-10-04 10:21:01 EDT)" skipped: maximum number of running i
Oct 04 10:22:01 RPZ-3 python[2132]: WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Execution of job " (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2019-10-04 10:22:01 EDT)" skipped: maximum number of running i
Oct 04 10:23:01 RPZ-3 python[2132]: WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Execution of job " (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2019-10-04 10:23:01 EDT)" skipped: maximum number of running i

Every time after reboot Sometime working.
Please give me the solution for this issue.

Please find below code for Barometer Sensor job creation.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import time
import datetime
import MySQLdb
import sys
import logging

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

logging.basicConfig()
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()

def EnterLog(text):
    print("[" + datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') + "] [SaveBarometerSensorData.py]: " + text)

def WaitForZeroSecond():
    flag = True
    while flag:
        sec = int(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%S'))
        time.sleep(1)
        delay = 56 #for raspberry pi zero board
        #delay = 59 #for raspberry pi III model B
        if (sec == delay):
            flag = False

def getToleratedDateTime(interval):
    tempDateTime = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time.time())
    sec = int(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%S'))

    if (interval < 60):
        addSec = 0
        tol = sec % interval
        if (tol > (interval / 2)):
            tempDateTime = tempDateTime + datetime.timedelta(seconds=interval)
        else:
            tempDateTime = tempDateTime - datetime.timedelta(seconds=tol)

    strTime = tempDateTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    return strTime

def SaveJob(pythonScriptPath, model, pin, state, interval, id):
    if (state == 1):
        strTime = getToleratedDateTime(interval)
        fileName = '/home/pi/projects/logs/PythonJobs_Log_' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H') + '.log'
        if not os.path.isfile(fileName):
            os.mknod(fileName)
        os.system("sudo chmod 777 " + fileName)
        command = "python " + pythonScriptPath + " " + str(pin) + " '" + strTime + "' " + str(id) + " >> " + fileName + " 2>&1"
        #Here calling sensor script with parameters.
        os.system(command)

try:
    sensorName = 'Barometer'
    # DB parameters
    hostname = 'localhost'
    port = 3306
    username = 'pi'
    password = 'password'
    database = 'SensorInformation'
    query = "SELECT ID, Name, PythonScriptPath, Model, Pins, MeasurementInterval, State FROM SensorSettings where Name='" + sensorName + "'"

    db = MySQLdb.connect(host = hostname, port=port, user = username, passwd = password, db = database)
    if (db):
        # print('Connected to MySQL database')
        cur = db.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        WaitForZeroSecond()
        for id, name, pythonScriptPath, model, pin, measurementInterval, state in cur.fetchall() :
            # Python schedular initialize 
            if (measurementInterval > 0) :
                scheduler.add_job(lambda: SaveJob(pythonScriptPath, model, pin, state, measurementInterval, id), "interval", seconds=measurementInterval,  id=sensorName + "SensorSaveDataJobId_" + str(id))
        cur.close()
        db.close()
        # Start the initialize.
        scheduler.start()
    else:
        EnterLog("Failed to connect database, " + e.message)
except Exception as e:
    EnterLog("Error: " + e.message)
```

Comment: Why not have 1 Python program running constantly checking all 5 sensors at periodic intervals - much simpler?

Comment: i need to get readings at a same time.

Comment: Maybe one of answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020161/python-apscheduler-skipped-maximum-number-of-running-instances-reached is helpful?

Comment: Add your Python code to your post.

Comment: I added my code also, the code only for one type of sensor. i am using 5 different types of sensors on single RPi device.